# Dealing with scope, uantity Cannot be Resolved to a variable Error, How to fix when using try-catch block

Tags: java, exception

I am dealing with an issue of scope that is giving me the "Quantity cannot be resolved to a variable error."

I know what it means, but I don't know how to fix it, given my code.

I am working on a BankAccount program dealing with quantity and price, and these have to be of type "Double".

I have to use a try-catch block to catch an exception, but this is causing me to receive the error. I know that variables have to be declared before we can use them, however, under this context, I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Here is my code:

```
//Validate Quantity
     nullpointerexception
     try {
         Double quantity = Double.parseDouble((request.getParameter("quantity")));

     } catch (Exception e) {
         hasError = true;
           request.setAttribute("quantityError", true);
           return;

     } 


       //Validate Price
        //Added after deadline to validate this entry and remove nullpointerexception    

            try{

    Double price = Double.parseDouble((request.getParameter("price")));


         } catch (Exception e) {
             hasError = true;
                request.setAttribute("priceError", true);
                return;

    } 


    // Redisplay the form if we have errors
            if (hasError){
                doGet(request, response);
                return;
            }
            else{
                // Cool, let's add a new description
                List<InventoryEntry> entries = (List<InventoryEntry>) getServletContext().getAttribute("entries");

                // Get a reference to the guest book
                //List<GuestBookEntry> entries = (List<GuestBookEntry>) getServletContext().getAttribute("entries");

                entries.add(new InventoryEntry(name, description, price, quantity));
                response.sendRedirect("BankAccounts");
            }

     }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `quantity` in a smaller scope than where you're attempting to access it from.

Before:

```
try {
    Double quantity = /* some val */;
} catch () {...}
System.out.println(quantity); //Quantity wasn't defined earlier?
```

After:

```
Double quantity = 0D; //default value
try {
    quantity = /* some val */;
} catch () {...}
System.out.println(quantity); //Prints our value or some default
```

When you leave a level of scope, your variables are "left behind" as well.

```
String one = "1";
{
    String two = "2";
    {
        String three = "3";
        //I can read one, two, three
    }
    //I can read one, two
}
//I can read one
```

Comment: thanks. This did the trick, but I have a different issue now.